# EclipseLink - No [EntityType] was found for the key class [...] in the Metamodel

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to use EclipseLink 4.0.2 with a SQLite database, but I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [EntityType] was found for the key class [com.mynamespace.MyClass] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Entity] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific com.mynamespace.MyClass property or a global false element.

I already have the `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` property in my persistence unit entry, so I don't know why it's not being recognized. The full persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <persistence-unit name="sqlite-2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:sqlite:./data.db" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the exception from, and where are you running this (ie in a container)? Have you tried statically generating the metamodel classes using build plugins like https://github.com/ethlo/eclipselink-maven-plugin ?